# Stop nodejs child_process with browser api call

Tags: node.js, express, kill, child-process

I have vue (axios) making a get call to an express route which triggers a child_process of ffmpeg in an infinite loop. ffmpeg streams one file over udp , on close it re calls itself and streams another file.

I'd like to be able to kill this process from a button on a web page, but can't seem to work it out.

This is my express route code

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  const childProcess = require('child_process');
  const fs = require('fs')
  const path = require('path')

  //Grabs a random index between 0 and length
  function randomIndex(length) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (length));
  }
  function Stream () {
  const FILE_SRC =  '/path/to/file'
  //Read the directory and get the files
  const dirs = fs.readdirSync(FILE_SRC)
    .map(file => {
      return path.join(FILE_SRC, file);
    });

  const srcs_dup = [];
  const hashCheck = {}; //used to check if the file was already added to srcs_dup
  var numberOfFiles = dirs.length - 1; //OR whatever # you want

  console.log(numberOfFiles)

  //While we haven't got the number of files we want. Loop.
  while (srcs_dup.length < numberOfFiles) {
    var fileIndex = randomIndex(dirs.length-1);

    //Check if the file was already added to the array
    if (hashCheck[fileIndex] == true) {
      continue; //Already have that file. Skip it
    }

    //Add the file to the array and object
    srcs_dup.push(dirs[fileIndex]);
    hashCheck[fileIndex] = true;
  }
  var chosen = "'" + srcs_dup[0] + "'"

  var call = "ffmpeg -re -i " + chosen + " -content_type audio/mpeg -f mp3 udp://224.1.2.3:1234"

  const stop = childProcess.exec(call, { shell: true });

  stop.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
  });

  stop.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  stop.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log ('child exited with code ' + code)
    Stream();
  });

  stop.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('sh error' + err)
  });
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any code about terminating the process, there's only this repeater on the `close` event... which you'll need to disable somehow, probably with an [`EventEmitter.removeListener`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener).

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new to javascript and node . I'm wasn't sure where to put the termination code.
After thinking about your answer i'm guessing I could send a msg from the client and remove the on close listener in the on message listener , then kill the process. Is that correct ?

Comment: I have been running ffmpeg in a bash script (child_process) , then triggering killall ffmpeg to stop the process , Are there any benefits to running ffmpeg as a child rather than using bash.

Comment: Indeed but then your server wouldn't be stateless anymore, which can be a problem. You could use sockets to avoid this, and/or triggering the looping from the client instead of infinite server loop. Anyway that's a big piece of coding ahead; there seems to be [many articles](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nodejs+stream+audio) (and probably packages) about streaming audio with Node, but that's clearly not the simplest thing to start with when learning Node and more generally JS. Well I'll say good luck and break a leg: if you persevere, you'll surely have quite a decent understanding of these!

Comment: Thanks.
I'm not streaming to a browser at all with this part of the project.The loop should just run constantly , though turning it off is required.
I'm thinking spawning a bash process containing the loop is the easiest way , though poss. not the most efficient.
I'll persevere and see where it leads me.
Thanks again.